# Is it possible to log the entire value of parameters in Exception traces?

Tags: php, exception

When reading over my error logs I notice that long parameters (such as SQL strings) are truncated in the Exception trace.  Here's an example:

`FR_Model`.php(204): FR_Base->query(**'INSERT INTO pos...'**, Array)

I'd like an easy way to echo the full parameter without having to roll my own Exception subclass. TIA.

Comment: Did you programming with the CodeIgniter MVC or another framework?

Comment: No, I'm using my own custom MVC framework.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `log_errors_max_len` PHP setting.  From [php.net](http://us.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors-max-len):

> *`log_errors_max_len`* `integer` - changeable: `PHP_INI_ALL`
>
> Set the
>   maximum length of `log_errors` in bytes.
>   In `error_log` information about the
>   source is added. The default is 1024
>   and 0 allows to not apply any maximum
>   length at all. This length is applied
>   to logged errors, displayed errors and
>   also to *`$php_errormsg`*.

**To test:** *([via this Bogus bug](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=41035))*

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors',0);
ini_set('log_errors',1);
ini_set('log_errors_max_len','0'); //change this value
ini_set('html_errors',0);

function deepTrace($a, $b, $c) {
    if ($c < 50) {deepTrace($a, $b, $c+1);} else {throw new Exception('Example exception that together with the trace is over 1024 bytes.');}
}
deepTrace('example','function',0);
?>
```

If changing `log_errors_max_len` in this sample code to 0 doesn't work, but changing it to a number larger than 1024 has some effect, then you are almost certainly loading a `zend_extension` somewhere that is overriding PHP's standard behavior, such as Zend Optimizer, Zend Debugger, Xdebug, etc.

Try `grep -r zend_extension /etc/php.*` to locate any extensions in use; if it finds a matching line that isn't commented out, there's your culprit.

Comment: Setting this to 0 didn't work. Perhaps this only pertains to errors, and not exceptions?

Comment: see above for a better example - if setting 0 still doesn't work, you almost certainly have a zend_extension in use that is causing your problems.